# send telemetry data async to azure iot hub with python wihout awaiting

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, azure-iot-hub

I want to send telemetry data to azure iot hub with python. I dont want to await the result. I always want to have one task
in the background for this. I dont need every result from every iteration in iot hub. When just using await the telemetry data is send, but it slows the iteration too much, so i decided to go this way. But with this way the data is not send, even the start one.

```
# ...

async def main():
    # ...

    CONNECTION_STRING = '******'

    task1 = asyncio.create_task(send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(CONNECTION_STRING, 'start'))

    while True:
       # ...
       
       result = calculate_result()

       # print all results to console
       print(result)

       # but i do not need to send all results to iot hub. Only send results when task1 is done. 
       if task1.done():
           await task1
           task1 = asyncio.create_task(send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(CONNECTION_STRING, result))

       # ...

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
# ...

async def send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(connection_string, data):
    try:
        async with IoTHubSession.from_connection_string(connection_string) as session:
            msg = Message(data, "utf-8", "application/json")
            await session.send_message(msg)
            return True
    except Exception:
            return False
```

Expected to send data to iot hub

Comment: `def  calculate_result():
return  "Dummy Result"
async  def  main():
CONNECTION_STRING = 'connectionstring'
client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)

await  client.connect()

task = asyncio.create_task(send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(client,  'start'))


while  True:

result = calculate_result()

print(result)
`

Comment: `if  task.done():

task = asyncio.create_task(send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(client,  result))


await  asyncio.sleep(1)  # Adjust the duration as per your requirement


async  def  send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(client,  data):

try:

msg = Message(data)

await  client.send_message(msg)

return  True
`

Comment: `except  Exception:

return  False

  
asyncio.run(main())`

Answer (score 0):

I have referred this MSDOC for [Azure IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/)  ,[Azure IoT Hub device for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/internet-of-things-show/azure-iot-hub-device-sdk-for-python) ,[azure-iot-device](https://pypi.org/project/azure-iot-device/) ,[asyncio Asynchronous I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) and Stack [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76263411/iot-edge-modules-life-cycle-and-communication-best-practices/76268679#76268679).

- If you want to send telemetry data to Azure IoT Hub without awaiting the result, you can use a fire-and-forget approach by creating a background task using `asyncio.create_task`.

**Sample code :**

```py
import  asyncio
from  azure.iot.device.aio  import  IoTHubDeviceClient
from  azure.iot.device  import  Message
async  def  calculate_result():
return  "Dummy Result"
async  def  main():
CONNECTION_STRING = 'IoTHubDevieConnectionString'

client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
await  client.connect()

task = asyncio.create_task(send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(client,  'start'))

while  True:

result = await  calculate_result()
print(result)

if  task.done():

task = asyncio.create_task(send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(client,  result))
await  asyncio.sleep(1)  
async  def  send_telemetry_to_iot_hub(client,  data):
try:
msg = Message(data)
await  client.send_message(msg)
return  True
except  Exception:
return  False
asyncio.run(main())
```

**Output :**

[image]

**In Azure:**

[image]

[image]